# How to setup MatBlazor so that controls are styled?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, matblazor

Trying to setup and use MatBlazor components in new .net 5 blazor webassembly. But, controls are not styled.

I followed the instructions at https://www.matblazor.com/.
Installed MatBlazor

```
dotnet add package MatBlazor
```

Added using to _imports

```
@using MatBlazor
```

added lines to index.html

```
<script src="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.js"></script>
<link href="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

registered service in program.cs

```
services.AddMatBlazor();
```

added MatPortalHost to app.razor

```
<MatPortalHost></MatPortalHost>
```

Added simple button

```
<MatButton> mat button </MatButton>
```

But my button has no styling. I tried a MatTextField too; no styling.

[image]

Did I miss a step? Are the setup instructions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to MatBlazor in your `<application>.Client.csproj`

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="MatBlazor" Version="2.8.0" />
```

[image: Example NatBlazor Button]

#### Note

Please pay attention that only preview version 2.9.0 has .net 5 official support:
[image: MatBlazor 2.9.0]

so is better to add the following reference:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="MatBlazor" Version="2.9.0-develop-042" />
```

but it's in **preview** !

Comment: Well, I changed the ref to your suggestion. Then, it worked (has styling). Yay. Then I changed it back to 2.8.0. Still works. Huh. I guess it works with both. Don't know why it didn't work for me yesterday. But it does today. I had a hunch that it was going to do that; just start working after a while. Thanks for reply. I'll give you the answer since it did start working after I made your suggested change.